# Login flow automation of application which uses aws cognito to login the use into the app

Tags: api-testing, postman, rest-assured, aws

I have an application where I need to automate the login flow using postman. The application UI accepts email and password but the thing is in the backend that application is using aws cognito to authenticate the user. So is there a way to achieve API automation for this kind of app? I tried researching about this on the internet but I did not found any solution.
Can anyone please help me on this?